# Google maps searchbox console errors

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I get these errors, apperantly he can't find some images. However these are out of my control because of the library.

```
GET file://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/powered-by-google-on-white2.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND VM3702:22
GET file://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/autocomplete-icons.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

This is the used library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running your website locally? Seems that the library is trying to fetch the file using the current protocol, which defaults to `file`.
Put your website on a local server and it should default to `http`